# How to manually manipulate TabItem Content property behind the code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question regarding Tab Item Content.

How do I specifically choose what is the current tab that is chosen and what do I put on this code, assuming this is the tabItem

TabItem TI = new tabItem();

TI.Content = *_*_ ?

How do I put it in code like if I want to put a user control/xaml page into the tab item content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just..

```
TI.Content = new yourUserControl()
```

but why here !! not in XAML?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to implement a dynamic tab items where whenever the user click a new tab just like in web browsers then the browser will load a new page/usercontrol. The problem with that is how will I determine what is the current tabItem since I don't see a property on my tabcontrol where it handles the current tab item selected?

Comment: well, just cast it as TabItem: TabItem page = myTabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;

Comment: Thank you so much! It's been more than hours for me figuring how to cast and select the current tab item.

Comment: Just a follow up question, let's say I have a user control test1.xaml and has a frame control name frame1.  On my second user control, how do I reference the test1.xaml in my test2.xaml in order to manipulate the property of the control in test2.xaml.cs? Because I know that test1 test = new test1(); will not work because im not instantiating it and not referencing it. May I ask how?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it, I think it's better to ask it as a new question (with more explain).